# Error code 100 fitting exp distribution using fitdist in r

Tags: r

I am trying to fit an exponential distribution to my data but I get the error below

```
"Error in fitdist(x41, "exp", method = "mle") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100"
```

I have tried mme which works but I have other distributions with mle so I need mle in exponential distribution as well. I have been stuck for days. Can anyone help me, please?

My data looks like this.

```
2795.5
304.6833
2786.45
5897.75
4381.367
1178.1
351.3167
109.85
459.6167
13.26667
0.033333
846.3833
3698.45
1527.1
94.31667
15.01667
271.8833
473
```

This is my code

```
ExpMle41 <- fitdist(x41, "exp", method="mle") 
ExpMle41
plot(ExpMle41)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the `fitdist` function come from? I don't have it in the base R packages...

Comment: fitdistrplus package

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming this is `fitdist` from `fitdistrplus` package, I can duplicate your error:

```
> fitdist(x41, "exp", method="mle")
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): non-finite finite-difference value [1]>
Error in fitdist(x41, "exp", method = "mle") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

but there's some large numbers in your data... maybe if we scale it all down by a factor...

```
> fitdist(x41/10000, "exp", method="mle")
Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
     estimate Std. Error
rate   7.1417   1.683315
```

Well that seemed to work. Let's scale by a bit less:

```
> fitdist(x41/1000, "exp", method="mle")
Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
     estimate Std. Error
rate  0.71417  0.1683312
```

Right. Divide by a thousand works. Let's keep going:

```
> fitdist(x41/100, "exp", method="mle")
Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
     estimate Std. Error
rate 0.071417 0.01682985
```

Fine.

```
> fitdist(x41/10, "exp", method="mle")
Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
      estimate  Std. Error
rate 0.0071417 0.001649523
```

So scaling the data by 1/10 works, and you can see how the estimate and SE scale. Let's go one more step:

```
> fitdist(x41/1, "exp", method="mle")
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): non-finite finite-difference value [1]>
Error in fitdist(x41/1, "exp", method = "mle") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

Crunch. It looks like some numerical stability problem with the underlying algorithm. If its taking exponentials of your data at any point then maybe it hits something indistinguishable from infinity. Like:

```
> exp(x41)
 [1]           Inf 2.100274e+132           Inf           Inf           Inf
 [6]           Inf 3.757545e+152  5.096228e+47 4.064401e+199  5.776191e+05
[11]  1.033895e+00           Inf           Inf           Inf  9.145540e+40
[16]  3.323969e+06 1.195135e+118 2.638092e+205
```

But scale by ten and the maths can cope, just about (E+256!!!)

```
> exp(x41/10)
 [1] 2.552833e+121  1.706977e+13 1.032728e+121 1.367817e+256 1.907002e+190
 [6]  1.459597e+51  1.809216e+15  5.898273e+04  9.139021e+19  3.768462e+00
[11]  1.003339e+00  5.727429e+36 4.184491e+160  2.094645e+66  1.247731e+04
[16]  4.489166e+00  6.423056e+11  3.484408e+20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate it.