# fitting distribution in R - error code 100

Tags: r

my data looks like this:

```
c(20000000.4, 2943143.86, 2223020, 3156203.17, 2581621.69, 45842102.64, 
2303396.3, 74924503.71, 2107205.28, 803526, 115984539.2, 2904623, 
6e+06, 4782296.13, 2354548.46, 2389383.84, 2288983.99, 4436729, 
7500000, 1045758.15, 2495385.48, 126794168, 5546141.72, 2238181.12, 
2471143.02, 4839064.67, 15293527.76, 24888213.71, 459745, 1790472.95, 
4730418.92, 7241093, 14574723.75
```

I am trying to fit the data to this distribution: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/actuar/versions/2.3-2/topics/SingleParameterPareto

```
require(actuar)
fit2 <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(lrg_clms, "pareto1",start=list(shape=1,min=12e6))
```

However it is coming up with an error of:

```
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
Error in fitdistrplus::fitdist(lrg_clms, "pareto1", start = list(shape = 1,  : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Not sure why it's going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error code 100 fitting exp distribution using fitdist in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557022/error-code-100-fitting-exp-distribution-using-fitdist-in-r)

Comment: Please dput(dlrg_clms).

Comment: @Christoph done

Comment: But see cettt s comment...

Comment: I don't understand how it's a duplicate - there should be large numbers as that is what I am trying to fit.

Comment: Try using different starting parameters. The initial values for the shape and min maybe too far from the solution for the algorithm to handle.